# Syntax Error When Trying preg_replace()

Tags: php, escaping, preg-replace, syntax-error

I'm trying to remove repeated slashes and while I'm tying it, I get errors. It seems some characters have to be escaped but I can't tell which one.

```
<?php
$path = preg_replace('(\\){2,}', '$1', 'z:\\\aaa\\\\bbb\c\ddd\');
echo $path;
?>
```

This gives,

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE

Could somebody fix this?

Comment: You don't have an IDE with syntax highlighting? Look at the highlighting in the question itself. You escape the end-quote for `z:...`. Download NetBeans or Eclipse, Teno.

Comment: I'm using Notepad++, not used to fancy IDE stuff.

Comment: Notepad++ doesn't have syntax highlighting? I just pasted this into Notepad++ and (again) the highlighting came up right away.

Comment: Yes it does but it doesn't highlight some functions so I haven't really trusted it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This part:

```
'z:\\\aaa\\\\bbb\c\ddd\'
```

should be:

```
'z:\\\aaa\\\\bbb\c\ddd\\'
```

You're escaping the closing quotation mark with a backslash, so the string doesn't end.

Comment: In my actual code, it is a variable. And it still says `No ending matching delimiter ')'`

Comment: @Teno: [I'm not getting that.](http://codepad.org/6XxINCGX) Your problem is probably in the preceding line. (Also, take a look at that codepad - there are a couple other fixes you need to make in your regular expression, namely delimiters and double-escaping.)